# Which test to use to compare multiple ratios when variability among groups is very different (cannot use ANOVA)?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, proportion

I am trying to see if the average proportion among different groups is same or there is atleast one group where the average proportion is different.

So I thought about using ANOVA but when I computed the standard deviations of different proportions among the different groups, they are very different. Hence I am stuck as to which test to use.

So following columns in my dataset are the point of focus

```
servicecenterid, grossrevenue, servicetime
```

servicecenterid is an id (nominal)
servicetime is in hours
grossrevenue is an integer

I am computing revenue_hours which is

```
revenue_hours = grossrevenue/servicetime
```

Then each service center is a group and I am then computing the average revenue_hours for each service center and I want to see that does atleast one proportion differ by using ANOVA.

But I cannot use ANOVA as each group's revenue_hours standard deviation is highly different

Comment: You need to be very cautious when taking an average of proportions because the sample size for each of the proportions need to be taken into account.

Comment: Ok so how should I approach the problem ?

Comment: You will need to give more details. For example, what are the proportions, how many are there, why are you averaging them?

Comment: sure let me edit the question

Comment: I have edited please see

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not clear to me. Where is the proportion? What do you mean by "Then each service center is a group"? 
Maybe you need to ask a question about how to deal with the uneven variability of the grossrevenue/servicetime ratio instead of a question about proportions. 
In any case, you should inspect the data in graphical form before trying to deal with the analysis.

Comment: grossrevenue/servicetime is the proportion

Comment: It is a ratio, but not a proportion in the usual sense. A proportion is  a fraction of a whole, and thus has no units. I have edited your question title.